# For of { onclick = () => } in Javascript: Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics

Tags: javascript, jshint

I'm getting a JSHint warning
[image: JSHint.com]

I was told my problem is: `onclick = () =>`
That is "function" in "for" (JavaScript).
Some one can help me fix that?

```
// Sentence Bold:
const word = document.getElementById('hanzi').innerHTML;
const sentence = document.getElementById('sentence').innerHTML;
if (word) {
    const words = word.split(' ');
    let sentenceBold = sentence;
    words.forEach(item => {
        sentenceBold = sentenceBold.replaceAll(item, '<b>' + item + '</b>');
    });
    const sentenceElement = document.getElementById('sentence-bold');
    sentenceElement.innerHTML = sentenceBold;
    const bolds = sentenceElement.getElementsByTagName('b');
    for (let el of bolds) {
        el.onclick = () => {
            writeHanzi(el.innerHTML);
            updateLookupHref(el.innerHTML);
        };
    }
    writeHanzi(bolds[0].innerHTML);
    updateLookupHref(bolds[0].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get any error? If you don't want to use an arrow function as a event handler, change it to: `el.onclick = function(event) { ... }`

Comment: Instead of `el.onclick...` you could try `el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {... your function body})`

Comment: Also, I see that in `words.forEach(item => { sentenceBold = sentenceBold.replace(...)})` you are repeatedly assigning new values to sentenceBold. I suppose, you want to append the words. So you could use `sentenceBold +=... `

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/KswFwvo.png This is the idea i want to implement, thank you so much for your support!

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of stuff going on with your code that is not ideal. I would almost say this particular jshint warning is the least of your problems.

When you want to set an elements content to bold conditionally you should use a css class.

You can add a css class to an element like this `el.classList.add("banana");`.

Also defining the onclick behaviour using `el.onclick = ...` is bad  practice because you can only define one listener this way for each object. Use `el.addEventListener("click",()=> ...)` instead.

My guess is that you are just starting to code and this is fine. Code is messy in the beginning :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't see much issues with the loop construction you currently have. But you can change your `onclick` function to make use of the `event` parameter to get the target that invoked the click event:

```js
el.onclick = event => {
  writeHanzi(event.currentTarget.innerHTML);
  updateLookupHref(event.currentTarget.innerHTML);
};
```

Or you can change the arrow function to a regular function expression and use the `this` to get the clicked element.

```
el.onclick = function() {
  writeHanzi(this.innerHTML);
  updateLookupHref(this.innerHTML);
};
```

In both cases, you're not referencing `el` inside of your callback function anymore.

I would recommend to use `.addEventListener` instead of `.onclick` so that you always can add additional event listeners, without overwriting the previous one. The `event` parameter or the `this` remain the same regardless of the one you use.

```js
el.addEventListener('click', function() {
  writeHanzi(this.innerHTML);
  updateLookupHref(this.innerHTML);
});
```